# Creating a test set where predicted variables are independent, ground truth variables are mutually exclusive. Two different classifiers

Tags: classification, categorical-data, binary-data

#### There are two classifiers;

1. `Classifier_A -> [A]` Classifier_A outputs a binary variable either A or nothing (implicitly not A).
2. `Classifier_B -> [B, C, D]` Classifier_B outputs any n-combination of B, C, D. All three variables are booleans. And a lack of an output implicitly implies that that output is false. Multi-class.

#### Problem:

Ground truth is not multi-class. The outputs are only one item from the set of `[A, B, C, D]`. And all 3 (or none of them) of the others are false.

I need to evaluate the performance of the two classifiers. **The immediate problem that stands out to me is that the ground truth variables are all mutually exclusive but the predicted variables are independent.**

How should I go about this? I have enough historical data to create a balanced dataset for all of the ground truth classes. What should my class breakdown look like? Can I evaluate the two classifiers separately? Is this even possible or is the premise of the testing flawed because of this discrepancy?